# Wanting all Images to have the same height in a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to have all images in my flex container have the same height using a 4:3 ratio, all of this being responsive.
When out of the flex container everything works well, but when put in it, it seems like it's the length of the title that dictates the width. I can't figure out why.

https://jsfiddle.net/ts8Lwp6g/

```css
/* Just copying the guy in vid for now, trying to figure it all out hopefully it won't be too much of a bother responsive eh ffs , somethings I haven't copied, tryna do best */

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#cccccc {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.w {
  background-color: red;
  /* doesnt show hay */
  display: block;
}

.views {
  float: left
}

.rating {
  float: right
}

.parentt {
  max-width: 258px;
}

.containertt {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  /* 34.37% = 100 / (w / h) = 100 / (640 / 220) */
}

.containertt img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.figcaptionnnn {
  /* background-color:red; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%
}

.figcaptionnnn a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tete.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="cccccc">
    <div class="parentt">
      <div class="containertt">
        <img height="145" width="258" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/221971.RajoRb.7fb2f73a-0b7d-4aa3-ac25-f0f31261cdae.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="figcaptionnnn">
        <span class="titlee"><a href=https://pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=1306454068 title="Tall french maid and batman" >Tall french maid and batman</a></span></br>
        <div class="w"><span class="views"> 692818 views</span><span class="rating">75 %</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parentt">
      <div class="containertt">
        <img height="145" width="258" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/221971.RajoRb.7fb2f73a-0b7d-4aa3-ac25-f0f31261cdae.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="figcaptionnnn">
        <span class="titlee"><a href=https://pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=1306454068 title="Tall french maid and batman" >Tall french maid and batman vdfvdsv dvdfv ddffv dvddv dvdcffc dvdfcd</a></span><br/>
        <div class="w"><span class="views"> 692818 views</span><span class="rating">75 %</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="parentt">
    <div class="containertt">
      <img height="145" width="258" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/221971.RajoRb.7fb2f73a-0b7d-4aa3-ac25-f0f31261cdae.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="figcaptionnnn">
      <span class="titlee"><a href=https://pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=1306454068 title="Tall french maid and batan" >Tall french maid and batman</a></span></br>
      <div class="w"><span class="views"> 692818 views</span><span class="rating">75 %</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parentt">
    <div class="containertt">
      <img height="145" width="258" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/i.cdpn.io/221971.RajoRb.7fb2f73a-0b7d-4aa3-ac25-f0f31261cdae.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="figcaptionnnn">
      <span class="titlee"><a href=https://pornhub.com/view_video.php?viewkey=1306454068 title="Tall french maid and batman" >Tall french maid and batman vdfvdsv dvdfv ddffv dvddv dvdcffc dvdfcd</a></span></br>
      <div class="w"><span class="views"> 692818 views</span><span class="rating">75 %</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I converted your fiddle into a native snippet. Next time include your markup here.

Comment: maybe simply specify a fixed width for `.figcaptionnnn` and it will fix the issue